# javascript replace one of multiple regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a script that reads a .txt file and puts it into a variable which looks like:

```
myString = "blablabla [12], foo bar bar[2], bar foo[34], hello hello [95], wheres my sandwich [2745]";
```

I managed to generate an array that contains all the values between brackets, to do so I used this line of code:`parameters = myString.match(/[^[]+(?=\])/g);`

So now I can easily get any of those values by calling `parameters[n]`

All I want to do now is to change the value of one of those elements between [ ], and inject it back to the string, but I don't know how to do it.
Of course if I use the following line:

```
myString = myString.replace(/[^[]+(?=\])/g, "newValue");
```

All the elements will be replaced so I will end up with a string like `blablabla [newValue], foo bar bar[newValue], bar foo[newValue], hello hello [newValue], wheres my sandwich [newValue]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts not only string, but also function as replacement. If you pass a function, the return value of the function is used as replacement string.

Using that feature:

```
var nth = 0;
myString.replace(/[^[]+(?=\])/g, function(match) {
    // Change only the 2nd matched string.
    return ++nth == 2 ? "newValue" : match;
});
// => "blablabla [12], foo bar bar[newValue], bar foo[34], hello hello [95],
//     wheres my sandwich [2745]"
```

Comment: you are just **fantastic**! thank you very much for the help.